# JS не может найти элемент по getElementById()

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, dom, type-error

Такая проблема: нашёл я себе симпатичный бэкграунд на codepen, решил его себе поставить. Скопировал всё как надо, часть изменил, все дела. Работало всё хорошо. Потом я делал остальную часть сайта, ставил библиотеки всякие, и короче сейчас вернулся к этому бэкграунду, а он в консоли пишет ошибку, мол - "Не могу найти тег по getElementById()".

Я долго ковырялся, даже отменил все изменения и попытался скопировать код как в изначальном варианте, но ошибка так и висела.. Так вот я нашёл странное "решение" - корректно всё работает только если поставить последний cdn после закрывающего тега .
Как это возможно?

Проект делал на Vue Cli, если это важно.

Скрин ниже из файла cdn, по идее там не должно же быть ошибок, раз на кодпене всё работает.

Ошибку пишет: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
[image: 1]

[Ссылка бэкграунда на codepen](https://codepen.io/jasperlachance/pen/QNMwBg)

```
если нужно - закину сюда код
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я вижу у вас [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/IIFE) (Immediately Invoked Function Expression). Скорее всего у вас скрипт срабатывает раньше рендера документа так что элементы не появились в DOM. Добавьте скрипт в конце страницы.

Comment: Вынул скрипт из cdn и вставил в mounted, таким образом всё работает. Можно ли это считать нормальным кодом?

Comment: Если работает то в чем проблема. Нормы у всех разные. Последний вопрос не совсем корректный.

Comment: В плане будет ли это чистым кодом по канону, или это скорее костыль? Я сейчас только обучаюсь разработке, хотелось бы понимать что есть хорошо, а что - плохо :)

Comment: @Altereyo это со временем прийдёт. Не думайте что всё у всех получается. Даже Майкрософт переписывает переодически код. И вам советую не бояться этого дела